# Docker Volume File permission

Tags: docker

I am going through the articles about docker volumes and understood there are different types like bind mounts and volumes etc ..

https://docs.docker.com/storage/

When it comes to the underlying file model, is it that a single copy is shard or there will be multiple copies - I mean, say ,  there 100 containers sharing the same file system, does each container will be seeing a shard file or each container will have a copy of file ?
And how the updates are handled - using some locks managed by the docker?

Answer (score 1):

All docker containers will be using same volume. As it appears in file system. Your OS will handle locks, same as it will do with directory for processes.

Comment: It is not clear, can you please elaborate this in terms of how docker handles or docker doesn't handle locks at all or it leaves it to the OS. Please share articles

Comment: Yes. Docker does not handle locks. It's same as you mount directory for virtual machine.

Comment: https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-volume-file-permission-and-locking/24335/2

Comment: Looking for more detailed and genuine answer, something in terms of  how it is implemented, perhaps some details about storage drivers (if they play any role at all or what role they play here in this case if the details are left to OS ? )